# How to access JobCounters and FileSystemCounters in Hadoop 2.6?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, counter

In the `Reducer` of my MapReduce program, I wish to read a `JobCounter` and a `FileSystemCounter`. When running the command `mapred job -status <job id>`, the counters I need are listed by their display names:

```
...
File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=148874
    FILE: Number of bytes written=22010065
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
    HDFS: Number of bytes read=135823
    HDFS: Number of bytes written=44423504133
    HDFS: Number of read operations=2185
    HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    HDFS: Number of write operations=1316
Job Counters 
    Launched map tasks=1
    Launched reduce tasks=200
    Rack-local map tasks=1
    Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=5293
    Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=972893
    Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=5293
    Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=972893
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=5293
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=972893
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=5420032
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=996242432
...
```

How can I access these counters at runtime from within my `Reducer`'s code?

Using Google, I fail to find any useful information on how to access these counters. The straightforward attempt using [Context.getCounter(String groupName, String counterName)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext.html#getCounter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) fails to retrieve a `Counter` instance and therefore throws a `NullPointerException` upon calling `getValue()`:

```
long bytes = context.getCounter(
    FileSystemCounter.class.getName(),
    FileSystemCounter.BYTES_WRITTEN.name()
).getValue();
long milliseconds = context.getCounter(
    JobCounter.class.getName(),
    JobCounter.MILLIS_REDUCES.name()
).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Counters counters = job.getCounters();

for (CounterGroup group : counters) {
      System.out.println("* Counter Group: " + group.getDisplayName() + " (" + group.getName() + ")");
      System.out.println("  number of counters in this group: " + group.size());
      for (Counter counter : group) {
        System.out.println("  - " + counter.getDisplayName() + ": " + counter.getName() + ": "+counter.getValue());
      }
    }
```

I think this will help to print all counters and their values.

Comment: Almost there; two questions: first, where does the variable `job` come from? Reducer.Context does not have a method that returns a `Job`. Second, why does `Reducer.Context.getCounter(String groupName, String counterName)` not work?

Comment: Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
Job job = Job.getInstance(cluster,conf);

Comment: Doesn't work at runtime; I get `java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING`. It appears `Job.getInstance()` creates a new `Job`, but I need the one that is currently running.